# how to copy a worksheet with code into same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have added a button to copy an active sheet and add to end of active workbook, which is working fine, but it doesn't copy the active worksheet VBA code.

```
Sub CopySheet()
'When button is press on the NEW sheet copies active worksheet to end of active workbook 
If ActiveSheet.Name Like "NEW**" Then
ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
On Error Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

code that I want copied to over when copied work sheet is copied.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'if PO number is updated the Active NEW sheet date is update to today's date.
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("d5")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("a8").Value = Now()
End If
End Sub
```

Doesn't copy VBA code, on Excel sheet

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Also that `On Error Resume Next` doesn't do anything here and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Sheet As Last Sheet With Condition

```vb
Sub CopySheet()
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    
    With ActiveSheet
        If .Name Like "NEW*" Then ' begins with "NEW" - case sensitive
           .Copy After:=.Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count) ' after last sheet
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```